# Configuring source dir for Sphinx documentation conf.py file

Tags: python, python-sphinx, devpi

I got a package that i am about to upload to a local devpi server. I got some issues with the package not being able to find the conf.py file for Sphinx which makes sense as it looks at the `(package_name)/docs` folder instead of `(package_name)/docs/source` which i use and also has all the RST files in it. How do i in pyproject.toml configure Devpi to set sphinx source_dir to `(package_name)/docs/source`?

It could surely be resolved in some way using `sys.path.append()` and then changing the path of the config but I do wonder about the configuration of this and if it is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update on this.
It is hardcoded in the devpi-client how it builds the docs.
I figured out that the devpi client have already been implemented to support `(package_name)/docs/source` dir.
Next version of devpi-client will include this, but it is still hardcoded to 2 paths and does not allow for putting it differently.

Answer (score 0):

In `devpi-client` version 5.2.3 it should work.
Because the change:
"Use `sphinx-build` command instead of `setup.py build_sphinx` when building documentation." in version 6.0.0 the upload routine doesn't "recognize" your local dir structure.
But I haven't find out yet how you can propagate arguments to the sphinx-build to specify the docs source dir.